# Finding the value of nth derivative at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=\arctan(x)$,

it can be shown that $$(1+x^2)y''+2xy'=0 \tag{A}$$

I need to find the value of nth derivative of $y$ when $x=0$.
Is it rigorous and right if l simply plug in the value of $x=0$ into equation $(A)$ and obtain $y''=0$.

Since $y''=0$ , the nth derivative will also be zero.

The answer expected is showing all the factors on the right side of the nth derivative of $y$ that clearly show it will be zero for various values of n but l think that's overdoing steps.

Comment: The $n$th derivative can't be $0$ for all $n$ because this function is analytic and that would make the Taylor series vanish.

Comment: The arctangent is an odd function, i.e. $\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$, so all its even derivatives are zero at $x=0$ but its odd derivatives are not

Comment: In fact $y'(0)=1$.

Comment: Does this help? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08540.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a set up of A way (it's not the only approach!) how to do this problem: Use series of arctan: $\sum_0\frac{(-1)^kx^{(2k+1)}}{2k+1}$. When taking the nth derivative at $x=0$, you are interested in the term carrying the exponent $2k+1=n$ because all terms with a lower exponent will go away after taking $n$ derivatives and all exponents higher will contain an $x$ which will become zero. If $n$ is even, it becomes evident that the nth derivative is zero, but if $n$ is odd, then you can extract the value of the derivative at $0$ by first solving $2k+1=n$ and use this $k$ to find the $nth$ derivative. Hint: it will be of the form $(n-1)!$ with a possible minus sign depending on $n$. Now you work out the details, otherwise the fun is gone

Comment: Thanks for the hint, l think it's clear now.